# typescript extract portion of string to process further

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am getting a string response as following:

```
{'url': <ImageFieldFile: photologue/photos/spiderman.png>}{'url': <ImageFieldFile: photologue/photos/superman_PucGOkm.jpg>}
```

I only need ***photologue/photos/spiderman.png*** and ***photologue/photos/superman_PucGOkm.jpg*** from this to construct concrete urls like following:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photologue/photos/spiderman.png

How can I do this in typescript?
My angular2 component function:

```
fetchGallery(id: number){

    this.showImages=true;
    this.galleryService.fetchGallery(id)
    .then( 
        response => {
            this.gallery = response;
            console.log(typeof(this.gallery._body))

        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let url = "{'url': <ImageFieldFile: photologue/photos/spiderman.png>}{'url': <ImageFieldFile: photologue/photos/superman_PucGOkm.jpg>}";
let array = url.match(/[A-Za-z0-9\/_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+/g)
```

In array you have extracted paths.

Comment: Yes this looks correct, however there could also be .jpg image like you can see in the returned string. So I will need to somehow extract both at the same time.

Comment: I have updated answer, now any file extension will be extracted

Comment: It's still somehow giving me only one string instead of two